# If X and Y are random variables and Y = aX + b, find a and b given Y∼ Bernoulli(1/2)

Tags: random-variables

I'm confused on how you approach these types of questions. I never know what to start with when I have 2 random variables that are related.

Suppose that X is a random variable which takes only two values −2 and +2, and that Y = aX + b where a and b are positive constants.

If Y ∼ Bernoulli(1/2), find a and b.

Comment: Yes I know the answers but I want to know how to approach these questions next time I'm asked

Comment: Hint: $Y$ can only be either $0$ or $1$. What can $a X +b$ be?

Comment: well, aX + b = 0 or aX + b = 1, but where does X's values come in? When Y is 1 X can be -2 or 2 and the same for Y = 0. I don't see it

Comment: Let's assume that when $X=-2$ then $Y=0$. It means that $-2a+b=0$ and $2a+b=1$. Solving it gives us $a=1/4$ and $b=1/2$. Check what happens in second case.

Comment: @mowzorn but how do you know to equate -2a + b = 0 and 2a + b = 1 instead of 0 = -2a + b and 0 = 2a + b for example?

Comment: I don't; in fact I did both of these cases and just explained one, but asked to check what happens in the second one. After doing both cases we see that only one solution is valid, because we have a constraint that $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Comment: @mowzorn oh okay thanks!